# GeoJSON<->TopoJSON roundtrip breaks leaflet on antimeridean

Tags: leaflet, geojson, topojson, antimeridian

For Wikipedia, I'm writing a service that extracts polygons of a country by a given ID, simplifies them, and produces GeoJSON.  The PostGIS query produces this GeoJSON:

```json
{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[
[[[179.16675595506,51.9554040068616],[179.183028487274,52.0533832939166],[179.242259803848,52.1241672041611],[179.521550607089,52.2320045907578],[179.765980758593,52.2319078127239],[179.999999974944,52.1384488027094],[179.999999974944,51.7940888148064],[179.763841869902,51.6997152871656],[179.574436853316,51.689260400522],[179.353476805577,51.7455660937973],[179.217039781909,51.8395464029174],[179.16675595506,51.9554040068616]]],
[[[-179.999999885112,51.7940888148064],[-179.999999885112,52.1384889958134],[-179.914841033482,52.0657268624567],[-179.883697790055,51.9764893877679],[-179.930211657151,51.864238501218],[-179.999999885112,51.7940888148064]]]
]}
```

The above shows fine in Leaflet 0.7, but if I encode it as TopoJSON for transmission and decode it at the client, it produces this GeoJSON which shows horizontal lines in Leaflet.  It seems TopoJSON is unable to preserve the `180` vs `-180`, and even though the original objects were split accurately along the date line, the result is broken.

I understand that this is a hard and well known problem, but I haven't been able to find an algorithm for solving this. My only guess has been to run through the points, and force the longitude 180 to -180 if there are any longitudes that are -180

```json
{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[
[[[-180,51.79407478509499],[179.74797479747974,51.6997364109946],[179.5679567956796,51.689260400522],[179.35193519351935,51.74554860186959],[179.20792079207922,51.83956129688793],[179.17191719171916,51.955394490403606],[179.17191719171916,52.05336961425355],[179.24392439243928,52.124150534752346],[179.53195319531955,52.2320045907578],[179.7839783978398,52.23189603106378],[-180,52.13842613451553],[-180,51.79407478509499]]],
[[[-180,51.79407478509499],[-180,52.13848041436253],[-179.92799279927993,52.06574541937144],[-179.8919891989199,51.97650935088983],[-179.92799279927993,51.8642586272767],[-180,51.79407478509499]]]
]}
```

Comment: https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/82

Comment: @BradHards I thought https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/pull/1293 shows that it is still being discussed. We are using the stable Leaflet (0.7), but #82 was closed over 2 years ago, so not sure which one it refers to.  One more thing - it seems that encoding/decoding to topojson is what actually causes this.